# Word used to describe a person's non-physical presence

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

What word could I use to describe a person who is dominating not only physically but also in knowledge, experience, and comprehension; someone who has a vast amount of experience?

Example of a sentence:

> Dominating the room with his physical and ________ presence...

Comment: Intellectual is a possibility. See also charisma; aura.

Comment: How about _gravitas_? Although it doesn't fit in the sentence.

Comment: I would say "dominating" would be a sufficient word by itself. If someone is "dominating" the room, that has a lot of ambiguity of which you can decide what the nature of the domination is. They can be dominating the room by a forceful occupation, which would definitely be a form of physical presence. Or, the word could be referring to how they are figuratively dominating the room with their very presence. Everything from their stance, demeanor and speech.

Comment: * . . . dominating the room with his physical form and suffusing it with his aura of wisdom*

Comment: "Dominating the room with his physical and legendary/renowned/esteemed presence." Seems you are talking about someone who is well-known for the attributes you listed.

Comment: The title and body of this question ask different things: the title asks for a non-physical presence, and the body for a non-physical dominating quality. Can you please edit your question to focus on either?

Comment: It's a bit vague - how are they dominating the room with their intellectual presence? By arguing with everyone, by slipping in the occasional word of wisdom, by reputation whenever anyone sees them because everyone knows how clever they are and is intimidated, or just by looking really smart like Einstein/Smart Hulk?

Comment: Prepossessing...

Answer (score 0):

A lot of words related to mind and soul can be used here, like:

> **psychic** or **psychical**: relating to the soul or mind.
>
> **emotional**: relating to a person's emotions.
>
> **spiritual**: not concerned with material values or pursuits.
>
> **inner**: mental or spiritual.
>
> **cognitive**: relating to cognition.
>
> **psychological**: related to the mental and emotional state of a person.
>
> **intellectual**: relating to the intellect.
>
> **mental or mindly**: relating to the mind.
>
> **psychogenic**: having a psychological origin or cause rather than a physical one.

Comment: Any particular one that you think is best?

Comment: I like the Psychogenic word.

Comment: Dominating the room with his physical and psychogenic presence...

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> Dominating the room with his physical and ***cerebral*** presence...

It is a near synonym of *intellectual*:

> **2a :** appealing to intellectual appreciation
>       ***cerebral*** drama
>
> **2b :** primarily intellectual in nature
>       *a **cerebral** society*
>       *books for **cerebral** readers*
>
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cerebral)</sub>

Comment: Spelled out definitions often miss the nuance; they fit by literal meanings but just don't considering all the unspoken associations. 'cerebral' means 'characteristic of thinking a lot' - people can be cerebral, but a presence really can't.

Comment: If a *society* can be cerebral, I fail to understand the objection to applying the term to a *presence*. It paints the proper picture.

Comment: The 'presence' thinks a lot and shows it or provokes a lot of thought? That just doesn't work for me. 'cerebral' is about the inner workings of something, not the external display.

Comment: You are providing an alternate definition of *cerebral* that is not in line with the definition I have cited in the answer. A lot of words have multiple meanings where one would work for the sentence and the other meaning would not. In this case, a *cerebral presence* is one where the person's presence raises the intellectual appeal of the gathering.

Comment: I am a science fiction author and the character I am writing about has lived for millions of years, is biological, is very tall, human in shape, but very muscular, extremely smart and has the experience as well. (Some background). So when the character enters the room his presence both physically and in demeanor is a very intimidating one.

Comment: What do you think regarding the word preternatural?

Comment: If you are after an intimidating presence, you may consider *indomitable* or *formidable*.

Comment: If you want to stress his intelligence and experience, perhaps consider *authoritative*.

Answer (score 0):

"**Persona**" could be used that way. It's meaning is, more or less, confined to the *projected* character, which according to Cambridge online is often a distinct  entity from the *real* character. However, since your question seems to point more to the perceived image than the real character that is hidden inside, it is a fitting word. The projected image of strength could very well reflect an interior reality.

> **persona** noun [ C ]
>
> the particular type of character that a person seems to have and that is often different from their real or private character:
> "He had a shy, retiring side to his personality that was completely at odds with his public persona." ([dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/persona))

And here is an example usage in a headline:

> **A dominant persona and its many downsides:**
> Those in a leadership position can easily end up putting off people than winning them over.
> ([gulfnews.com](https://gulfnews.com/business/analysis/a-dominant-persona-and-its-many-downsides-1.1495209))

Your example sentence [fragment] asks for an adjective, but using *persona* it could be rephrased:

"Dominating the room was his persona..."

Answer (score 0):

Charismatic

Charisma means, a person's essence, power of spirit, influence, and light. The essence that is felt, or sensed, even from across the room.

It is their 'non-physical' presence, which is not a part of 'intellect or mind' as others have stated - rather, it is about personal energy, and soul.

Example:
Before she even said a word, I knew I had to meet her - such was her charisma.

Etymology — The English term charisma is from the Greek χάρισμα (khárisma), which means "favor freely given" or "gift of grace".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charisma